# flexbox div under one div without using flaot property

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>
    .container{
        display: flex;
        gap: 5px;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow:auto;

    }
    
    .container .one{
        background-color: blue;
        align-items: stretch;
       
        flex-basis: 300px;
       
       
    }
    
    .container .two{
        background-color: blue;
       
        flex-shrink: 30px;
        
    
    }
    .container .three{
        background-color: blue;
        
        flex-basis: 950px;
    }
    .four{
        background-color: blue;
        float: left;   }
</style>
<body>
   
</body>
```

[How to make this all using Flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGn3M.png)

I have done using everything but have been unable to achieve exact results.  Can someone help me achieve this using Flexbox without using float also without using bootstrap.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Your html structure is missing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        * {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        .container {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            gap:20px;
            margin:10px;
        }
        .row {
            display:flex;
            gap:6px;  
        }
        .row:last-child {
            gap:0;
        }
        .top-boxes {
            background-color:rgb(6, 85, 124);
            border:4px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            height:400px;
            padding-top:20px;
        }
        .bottom-boxes {
            background-color:aqua;
            border:4px solid black;
            text-align: center;
            padding:14px;
            color:blue;
        }
        .top-boxes:nth-child(1) {
            flex-grow:2;
        }
        .top-boxes:nth-child(2) {
            flex-grow: 0.5;
        }
        .top-boxes:nth-child(3) {
            flex-grow: 5;
        }
        .bottom-boxes:nth-child(1) {
            flex-grow:5.5;
        }
        .bottom-boxes:nth-child(2) {
            flex-grow: 3;
        }
        .bottom-boxes:nth-child(3) {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row top">
            <div class="top-boxes">
                <h3>
                    Confused
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="top-boxes">
                <h3>
                    Happy
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="top-boxes">
                <h3>
                    Sad
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row bottom">
            <div class="bottom-boxes">
                <h3>
                    Warm
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-boxes">
                <h3>
                    Cool
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-boxes">
                <h3>
                    Hot
                </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why didn't we use flex basis property?

Comment: im not sure but its better i think, in flex-basis u should give width with 'px' or '%' , but in flex-grow u just give numbers that will divides into equal sections, for example i gave top-boxes 2+0.5+5 that is 7.5 so my width has 7.5 sections that 2 of them are for first box 0.5 for 2nd and 5 for the last one.

Comment: what does flex shrink do

Comment: if you have two boxes with 300px width, so if you use flex-shrink: 3; for the 2nd box    "300 x 1/3 = 100px", first box 300px and 2nd will be 100px :D

Comment: when using flexbox we don't use any padding or margin?

Comment: we can use margin but gap its just better, when you use margin-left you should use .classname:not(:first-child) {margin-left:10px} ,but with gap you don't need to do that, yes you can use padding too

Comment: we can't use flex properties on items in a div?

Comment: I don't get what you say ":D